# Software on a VMs level of access to base PC

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, security, privacy

I'm wondering the level of access a piece of software installed on a Windows 7/10 VM, using something along the lines of virtual box, has to the base PC?

For example, I own death stranding on Steam but it requires Denuvo, Denuvo needs ring 0 access, I don't like that. If I installed it on a VM what kind of level of access would it have to my PC, and if I delete the VM will all traces of Denuvo go with it?

(Apologies if this isn't the place for Windows questions)

Answer (score 0):

A VM has no file access to the host PC. It may may have access to shared folders,
if you have defined any, but that's all.

On the other hand, it lives inside your local network and, if infected, can attack
the host. To avoid that, if your router supports subnets or VLANs,
you may connect the VM to a separate subnet.
For VirtualBox you may also use
[internal networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal).

If you delete the VM, then all is gone, if the VM files are truly deleted.